# Python parsing certain words from text

Tags: python-3.x, string, parsing, cpu-word, accumulator

i am looking to count specific mentions of the word blood in a text but i haven't gotten very far. i've tried several things and the farthest i have gotten is being able to parse out all sentences containing the word. this is what i have thus far, which is finishing with exit code 0

```
 infile = open('C:\IS452\week7\dracula.txt', 'rt', encoding = 'utf=8')
    dracula_lines = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    for blood_lines in dracula_lines:

    accumulator = blood_lines.strip()


    dracula_lines.count("blood")
    if "blood" in dracula_lines:
        print("blood") in str(newText[blood_lines + 1])
    #print(blood_lines)

    blood_lines = accumulator.split("blood")
    newText = ("There are this many mentions of blood in Dracula", blood_lines)
      print(newText)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [.count()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count) on the string directly:

```
with open('C:\IS452\week7\dracula.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf=8') as f:
  dracula_txt = f.read().lower()

blood_count = dracula_txt.count("blood")
print(blood_count, "mentions of blood in Dracula")
```

If you are doing this for some coding challenge where you are not allowed to just use .count(), then maybe you can do something like:

```
dracula_list = dracula_txt.split("blood") # split text into list separated by occurrences of "blood"
blood_count = len(dracula_list) - 1 # count of occurrences is the length of the list minus one
```

If you think this would also be cheating, then you can try something like:

```
index = blood_count = 0
while(index != -1):
  try:
    # we get the position of the next occurrence of "blood" in the string, starting from the position of the last occurrence plus one
    index = dracula_txt.index("blood", index) + 1
    blood_count += 1
  except ValueError: # when there aren't any more occurrences of "blood" in the string, we get a ValueError and exit the loop 
    index = -1
print(blood_count, "mentions of blood in Dracula")
```

Or you can iterate through every character in the string, checking if the substring following the character index matches "blood" and increment the count accordingly:

```
blood_count = 0
for i in range(0, len(dracula_txt)):
    if dracula_txt[i:i+5] == "blood":
        blood_count += 1
print(blood_count)
```